# Probability of extracting none of a certain thing out of multiple extractions

Tags: probability

In a wallet there is five $ \$1 $ bills, four of $ \$2 $ and two of $\$5$, all of them have equal probability of being extracted. If three bills are extracted at the same time, what is the probability of extracting none of $\$1$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried doing (6/11)*(5/10)*(4/9), which is giving me 4/33 but I'm really sure that I made a mistake.

Comment: Good! Next time you can include your working in the question, people will appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of not choosing a $ \$1 $ bill on the first extraction is $\frac{6}{11}$ because there are 6 other bills and 11 in total.

On the second extraction the probability of not getting a $ \$1 $ bill is $\frac{5}{10}$ because there are 5 other bills and 10 in total (since one is removed).

On the third extraction the probability of not getting a $ \$1 $ bill is $\frac{4}{9}$ because there are 4 other bills and 9 in total (since two are removed).

Hence, the probability of not getting a $ \$1 $ bill on all three extractions is $\frac{6}{11}\times\frac{5}{10}\times\frac{4}{9}=\frac{4}{33}$